# Formatting tips below the body textbox of a post are wrong

Tags: bug, code-formatting, help, blockquote

When posting a question or answer, there is a formatting help below the body textbox, which includes tips for how to format code, make text bold or italic, and quote text:

> [image: screenshot showing formatting tips below body textbox]

However, the tips for formatting code and quoting text are wrong. I explain below:

- **For formatting code**, the help shows inline code formatting using code fences (triple backticks) as ```` ```code``` ````. However, while multiple backticks can be used for formatting inline code, the general consensus (also reflected in the [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code)) is that inline code should be formatted using single backticks as `` `code` `` and multiple backticks should be used for special cases (such as escaping a backtick inside inline code) or for formatting code blocks.

  The *Code* section of *Show formatting tips* shows the correct way of formatting inline code and code blocks:

  > [image: screenshot showing correct tips for formatting code]

  Additionally, as [@Marijn said in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398239/formatting-tips-below-the-body-textbox-of-a-post-are-wrong#comment1329596_398239):

  > [...] to be consistent with the tips for bold and italic it would be better if the first tip would show the code as monospace with a gray background, instead of formatted as kbd.
- **For quoting text**, the help shows quote formatting as `>quote`. However, this doesn't work since there should have been a space between `>` and `quote`. The correct tip should be `> quote`.

  The *Blockquotes* section of *Show formatting tips* shows the correct way of quoting text:

  > [image: screenshot showing correct tips for quoting text]

  As in the case of inline code formatting, to be consistent with the other tips, it would be nice if the quote formatting tip was displayed as rendered quote formatted text.

Comment: Inline quoting can be any number of quotes, the same at start and end. The benefit of showing more than one is it works if the quoted text contains a backquote, while that's much more likely than it containing 3. Code blocks can be by indentation, fences are not  necessary.

Comment: @philipxy while it's true that triple backticks can be used for inline code (and that code blocks can be indicated by indentation), these quick formatting tips should show regular usage, which is one backtick for inline code and three backticks on separate lines around the code for code blocks.

Comment: By the way, to be consistent with the tips for bold and italic it would be better if the first tip would show the code as monospace with a gray background, instead of formatted as kbd.

Comment: @philipxy I edited the question to explain that single backticks are the general consensus for inline code formatting, not that multiple backticks don't work. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Marijn Excellent observation! Somehow I missed that. I edited your comment into the question so it's easier to be seen. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I mostly wanted to correct. PS Trying to tell people things in too small a space is pointless & misleading. Wishing it wasn't pointless & misleading doesn't change that.

Comment: The `>quote` syntax used to work before the adoption of CommonMark in 2020. I think the help simply hasn't been updated since.